# Agent Presentation Does not Render

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to Anylogic, and currently working my way through the "Anylogic in 3 days" tutorial.

Having said that, I cannot get the images of a forklift to render when running my model.  I have even tried opening the "completed" files made available by Anylogic and when I run them locally the forklifts do not appear!

Clearly I'm missing something obvious, so if anyone can provide some insight that would be greatly appreciated.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Follow Procedure described here: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/job-shop/2-add-resources.html
2. Run Simulation

Expected Result:

1. Forklifts should appear in simulation.

Actual Result:

1. Forklifts do not appear (see linked screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t1Ha.png)

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to Anylogic support, and apparently the issue I'm experiencing is a bug.

Here is their exact feedback, along with a proposed workaround:

> It is a known problem specific for macOS Monterey: 2D representation of 3D objects is not visible, while you can see 3D objects in 3D. We are currently working on a solution to the problem.
>
> As workaround, you can use shapes from the "Presentation" palette in addition to 3D objects as animation for agents. Thus, you will see agents in both 2D and 3D.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably rendered under the warehouse layout, so you need to bring them to front. Go to the top left corner of your main agent, select all the agent images there, then right click, then click bring forward.

Comment: Yashar, thanks for taking the time to respond.  I've tried the solution you suggested (i.e. make sure the warehouse image is not rendered over the forklifts)., Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Another thing to mention is that I cannot even see the presentation image when viewing the agent diagram.  Here is a screenshot to illustrate my point.  https://ibb.co/PjKDbcd.  Have you ever experience this type of issue before?

Comment: It seems that you have done something wrong. I would delete this agent and recreate it. Don't forget to select an icon for the forklift when going through the agent creation wizard.

Comment: Or you might have selected white/transparent color. Click on the front part of the agent representation (as opposed to the group selection that you have done in the screenshot). Choose different color at the right side (properties panel)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that your agent presentation is actually created. This can be easily missed if you accidentally deleted it or created agent types in a non-standard way.

1. Click on your agent population or instance within Main
2. in the properties at the bottom, click the "Show presentation" button, if it is clickable:
   [image]

(If it is grayed out, that means all should be well and you have a presentation object to be rendered)